# ObservableCollection<> vs. List<>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have lots of entities with nested `List<>` in each.

For example, I have `BaseEntity` which has `List<ColumnEntity>`.
`ColumnEntity` class has `List<Info>` and so on.

We are working with a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) UI, and we need to track all changes in every List of `BaseEntity`. It is implemented by instantiating a `new ObservableCollection` based on the needed list, and with binding to that `ObservableCollection`.

What are the pros and cons changing all these nested `Lists` to `ObservableCollections`? So we can track all changes in `BaseEntity` itself without reassigning each list of `BaseEntity` to modified bound `ObservableCollection`?

Assuming that methods specific to `List` are never used.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Interesting question, considering that both `List` and `ObservableCollection` implement `IList<T>` there isn't much of a difference there, `ObservableCollection` also implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, which allows WPF to bind to it.

One of the main differences is that `ObservableCollection` does not have `AddRange` method, which might have some implications.

Also, I would not use `ObservableCollection` for places where I know I would not be binding to, for this reason, it is important to go over your design and make sure that you are taking the correct approach in separating layers of concern.

As far as the differences between `Collection<T>` and `List<T>` you can have a look here
[Generic Lists vs Collection](https://web.archive.org/web/20160523222548/http://netundocumented.com:80/2004/08/generic_lists.html)

Comment: I fixed the link and the change was approved.

Answer (score 44):

It depends on exactly what you mean by this:

> we need to track all changes in every List of BaseEntity

Would it be enough to track changes to objects already in the list? Or do you need to know when objects are removed from/are added to/change positions within the list?

If a list will contain the same items for their whole lifetime, but the individual objects within that list will change, then it's enough for just the objects to raise change notifications (typically through `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and `List<T>` is sufficient. But if the list will contain different objects from time to time, or if the order changes, then you should use `ObservableCollection<T>`.

So while the differences may be interesting (and a previous poster has already covered those), typically you won't have that much of a choice - either you need `ObservableCollection<T>` or you don't.

Answer (score 13):

List represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by index. It provides methods to search, sort, and manipulate lists. The List class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It implements the IList generic interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.

ObservableCollection is a generic dynamic data collection that uses an interface "INotifyCollectionChanged" to provide notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole collection is refreshed.

Read more about it in this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha

Answer (score 11):

One more important difference is you can access ObservableCollection only from thread on which it was created where as list can be accessed fromany thread.

Comment: Untrue. You can access both from any thread. But when ObservableCollection is bound to an ItemsControl, if a change is triggered from non graphical thread, it will modify a graphical object from a non graphical thread. And it is forbidden -> exception

Answer (score 7):

I see no problem with that, other than a very marginal performance overhead.

Note that if you modify the internal Lists directly, you are not notified about changes. Also if the objects which are contained in the ObservableCollection are modified you are not notified. Notification occurs only, if elements are added, replaced, removed or moved.