# Unable to bind data in combo box in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am having a combo box in data grid in WPF. I am unable to bind data. I have used the below code.

XAML

```
<DataGrid 
   Name="grdDetails" 
   Width="578" 
   Height="149" 
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
   MouseRightButtonUp="grdDetails_MouseRightButtonUp" 
   SelectionChanged="grdDetails_SelectionChanged">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" Header="Country">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ComboBox 
                  Name="cbCountry" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CountryList}" 
                  SelectedItem="Code" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Code" 
                  SelectedValuePath="Code"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code Behind (C#)

```
List<CountryDTO> CountryList = new List<CountryDTO>();
CountryList = refController.GetCountryData();  // this brings the list of Country.
```

Please advice.

Comment: Where is `CountryList` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MVVM you need to create a view model class which would look like below and in your code behind assign an instance of it to the DataContext property of the Window.

Then the binding would like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CountryList , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
```

The view model class would look like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<CountryDTO> CountryList { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel(SomeControler refController)
    {
        CountryList = new ObservableCollection(refController.GetCountryData());
    }
}
```

Comment: MVVM is not a silver bullet so there might be no need here to use that, but the OservableCollection is important!

Answer (score 2):

You really could have so many problems, judging by that tiny spec of code that you showed us... in no particular order, please check the following:

1) Please ensure that your `grdDetails DataGrid` has its `ItemsSource` property set to a valid collection of items, or there will be no data in the `DataGrid`... I'm assuming that you foolishly left that out of your code example for brevity.

2) Please ensure that your `Binding` from the `ComboBox` is in scope. If you are trying to data bind to a single collection then this `Binding` will not work:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbCountry" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CountryList}" ... />
```

The above `Binding Path` is in the scope of the `ComboBoxItem`s, so to make this work, you'd need to add a `CountryList` collection property to every one of the data bound items to be displayed in the `ComboBox`. To make this work with just one collection in the object that is data bound to the parent `DataContext` property, you'd need to use this `Binding Path`:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbCountry" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.CountryList, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourView}}}" ... />
```

3) In an ideal world, your data items should be in an `ObservableCollection` rather than a `List`. From the [`ObservableCollection<T>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

4) It is unwise to use Data Transfer Objects (DTO) as your model items in WPF, unless they implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface. Even if they do, it is almost always preferable to define your own custom data type classes that provide all of the properties required for editing *and displaying* in the UI... we often need to add properties just to help to visualise things in the UI.

5) Please ensure that you have set a valid instance of an object to the `DataContext` of the `Window` or `UserControl` that you are using.

6) Please ensure that your object that is set as the `DataContext` actually has data coming into it.

While there *are* still further reasons why you may not have any data in your `ComboBox`, I've unfortunately run out of time... I have already listed the most likely causes of your problem, but for future reference, perhaps you could [provide all of the relevant information in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 1):

If CountryList is defined in the CodeBedind (not the DataContext) you will need a RelativeSource as well:

```
... ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourView}}, Path=CountryList,}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ObservableCollection, not a list then the added objects should be available. More info here: [ObservableCollection<> vs. List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196968/observablecollection-vs-list)

Comment: I am not using list instead using a DTO class.

Comment: Your ComboBox.ItemsSource is Bound against countrylist, which is of type List<WHATEVER>... GenericLists don's fire ChangeNotifications if any objects are added or removed...
BTW... your replacing the whole list after the new List<...> call. It would be better to just initialize it correct with the method or use AddRange.