# WPF List inside List Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using nested ListBox for databinding,
This is my ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lst1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListDS}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <ListBox Height="300" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding userFiles }" Margin="0,10" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <Button Content="Print" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

These are my entities

```
public class UsersInfo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUploaded { get; set; }
    public List<UsersFiles> userFiles { get; set; }
}
public class UsersFiles
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateDownloaded { get; set; }
}
```

and in my ViewModel, I have this

```
public List<UsersInfo> ListDS{ get; set; }
```

I am initializing it in my ViewModel's constructor and this is how I am populating the data

```
UsersInfo entity = new UsersInfo();
entity.MediaFiles = new List<UsersFiles>();
UsersFiles mFiles = new UsersFiles();                           
mFiles.Name = "abc";
mFiles.Id = 1
entity.Name = "User name";
entity.MediaFiles.Add(mFiles);
ListDS.Add(entity);
```

The problem is, ListBox is appearing blank, nothing is showing on it,even Print button.
When I added ListBoxItem in it,its showing perfectly.
Where I am doing wrong in databinding?

Comment: what is your viewmodel? where do you set the DataContext? the exact order of setting the DataContext here is important, I guess you set the DataContext ***before*** adding some entity to the `ListDS`, it's OK if your `ListDS`'s change is notified using INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The interface will notify the view when the property changes.

But you want your view to be notified if there is any new item in the collection so it's better to use a collection that will do that for you. Use `ObservableCollection<UserInfo>` to expose your `ListDS`.

```
public ObservableCollection<UserInfo> ListDS
{
    get { return listDS; }
    set
    {
        listDS = value;
        // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
        OnPropertyChanged("ListDS");
    }
}

// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using List<UserInfo> can I use ObservationCollection instead of List?

Comment: Yes, both collection implement `IList<T>` interface so your code shouldn't suffer any incompatibility. The advantage of `ObservableCollection` is that it also implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. In this answer you will find bit more on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4197068/3330348

Answer (score -1):

assuming your view-model code is correct you only need to change this:

`<ListBox Height="300" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ListDS2}" Margin="0,10" >`

to this:

`<ListBox Height="300" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding userFiles}" Margin="0,10" >`

and it will work. note the incorrect binding value !

Comment: i made a sample with exactly this code. i don't understand what your problem is exactly. the single item is displayed properly in my sample. you say nothing about wishing to update the UI as a result of code changes after the UI is displayed.