# Add and bind with a list of data a user control in a WPF windows

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have created a WPF user Control and i want to use it into a WPF windows and display it as a list.

I have in in the code behind of my main windows a list of data that i add to a listview, and i want to add to that list my user control in a way where the UC get also the data. If i have a list of 3 items, i want my UC to be called three times and bind correct data. When i run my solution, it works, but display 4 empty rows.

I try with a list but maybe another display is better.

- how can i set the data to the user control?
- did i do it the good way?

My main windows WPF :

```
<Window xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:myWpfTest.Views.Controls"
        x:Class="myWpfTest.Views.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize"  
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid x:Name="MainWindows">
        <Controls:UpperRibbon Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView Margin="0,90,0,0" Name="lvSessions" Background="Transparent">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Controls:Call Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My main windows code behind :

```
namespace myWpfTest.Views
{
    public partial class Test : Window
    {
        private Params _params = new Params();

        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Background = _params.BackGroudPicture;
            var param = _params.GeneralParam;

            List<Session> items = new List<Session>();
            items.Add(new Session() { Hour = "10 : 20", Message = "5sq465dq465d4q d 5sqd4qs65d4q ds65qd 4s65d4qs6d4q", Start = "Salle 01", End = "Bloc 01" });
            items.Add(new Session() { Hour = "11 : 20", Message = "5sq465dq465d4q d 5sqd4qs65d4q ds65qd 4s65d4qs6d4q", Start = "Salle 01", End = "Bloc 01" });
            items.Add(new Session() { Hour = "13 : 10", Message = "5sq465dq465d4q d 5sqd4qs65d4q ds65qd 4s65d4qs6d4q", Start = "Salle 02", End = "Bloc 01" });
            items.Add(new Session() { Hour = "16 : 35", Message = "5sq465dq465d4q d 5sqd4qs65d4q ds65qd 4s65d4qs6d4q", Start = "Salle 04", End = "Bloc 02" });            

            lvSessions.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }

    public class Session
    {
        public string Hour { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Start { get; set; }
        public string End { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My user control WPF :

```
<UserControl x:Class="myWpfTest.Views.Controls.Call"
             x:Name="CallUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbHour" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="4,4,4,4" Padding="10,0,10,0" Foreground="White" FontSize="28">
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=Hour}"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Message" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="4,4,4,4" Padding="10,0,10,0" Foreground="White" FontSize="28">
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=Message}" />
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Start" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="4,4,4,4" Padding="10,0,10,0" Foreground="White" FontSize="28">
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=Start}"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="End" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="4,4,4,4" Padding="10,0,10,0" Foreground="White" FontSize="28">
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=End}"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

EDIT :

Main WPF :

```
<Grid Name="test2"></Grid>
```

Main Code behind : I'll start from that and call my UC as needed

```
Controls.Call myUC = new Controls.Call();
myUC.Hour = "test test";
Grid.SetRow(myUC, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(myUC, 0);
test2.Children.Add(myUC);
```

Comment: I solve my problem of binding by replacing listview in my main windows WPF by a simple grid.

I edit my main message to show how.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a List try using an Observable collection in your code behind.

ObservableCollection< Session > items = new ObservableCollection< Session >();
Whenever you try to render a collection in WPF it should use an observable collection. 
Please have a look at this for more info:
[ObservableCollection<> vs. List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196968/observablecollection-vs-list)

Comment: You should also look to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your Session class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  This will make the UI update when a value changes withing the class.

Comment: Thanks, i switch my list with ObservableCollection. It should be helpfull when i'll be at that point in my building.