# WPF Listview not displaying list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a wpf MVVM project that I am working on, I am using prism so INotifyPropertyChanged = SetProperty. I have a model that is ComplaintModel:

```
public class ComplaintModel:BindableBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private Person _complaintPerson;
    private List<EmployeeModel> _crewList;

    public string MyStreet { get; set; }
    public string Complaint { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfResponse { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public bool? Callout { get; set; }
    public string Quad { get; set; }
    public string Tap { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

    public Person ComplaintPerson
    {
        get { return _complaintPerson; }
        set { SetProperty(ref (_complaintPerson), value); }
    }

    public List<EmployeeModel> CrewList
    {
        get { return _crewList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref (_crewList), value); }
    }

    public int ComplaintID { get; set; }
```

and the property in the ViewModel:

```
private ComplaintModel _selectedComplaint;
public ComplaintModel SelectedComplaint
{
    get { return _selectedComplaint; }
    set { SetProperty(ref (_selectedComplaint), value); }
}
```

The EmployeeModel is

```
public class EmployeeModel:BindableBase,IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _phone;
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref(_firstName),value); }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref(_lastName),value); }
    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set { SetProperty(ref (_phone), value); }
    }
```

So I try to addEmployee:

```
private void AddEmployee()
{

    if (SelectedEmployee == null)
    {
        SetMessage(Messages.ChooseEmployeeMessage);
        return;
    }
    if (IsReadOnly)
    {
        SetMessage(Messages.MakeEditableMessage);
        return;
    }
    if (SelectedComplaint.CrewList == null)
    {
        SelectedComplaint.CrewList = new List<EmployeeModel>();
    }

    var myList = SelectedComplaint.CrewList;
    var employee = new EmployeeModel() {FirstName = "James", Id = 1, LastName = "Tays", Phone = "1234567"};
    myList.Add(employee);
    employee = new EmployeeModel() { FirstName = "John", Id = 2, LastName = "Doe", Phone = "1234567" };
    myList.Add(employee);
    SelectedComplaint.CrewList = myList;
    SelectedEmployee = null;
}
```

This adds the two employees to the CrewList but doesn't update the view.The funny thing is when I change `var myList = SelectedComplaint.CrewList` to `var myList = new List<EmployeeModel>();` it will add the 2 employees and update the view.
I have also tried the `SelectedComplaint.CrewList.Add(employee)` and this didnt update the view.

please let me know if you see an area that I have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Add will not be treated as changing the property. Here's why:
When you do:

```
    var myList = SelectedComplaint.CrewList;
    var employee = new EmployeeModel() {FirstName = "James", Id = 1, LastName = "Tays", Phone = "1234567"};
    myList.Add(employee);
    employee = new EmployeeModel() { FirstName = "John", Id = 2, LastName = "Doe", Phone = "1234567" };
    myList.Add(employee);
    SelectedComplaint.CrewList = myList;
```

You:

1) Call the getter of the `CrewList`. This return a REFERENCE to `_crewList` object

2) You `Add` the `Employee` - this modifies the list, but this doesn't call the setter of the `CrewList` - thus, view is not notified of the modified list

3) You set the `CrewList` property to the value of the myList variable. But, notice what I said in point 1 - `myList` is a REFERENCE to the same object - this will not change your property (probably Prism is not notifying the view if the object is not changed in the setter)

My suggestion is to change the `List` to be an `ObservableCollection` - this class has an additional "event" called `NotifyCollectionChanged` - which is automatically raised by the `ObservableCollection` when you call `Add()`, `Remove()` etc. This will notify the View for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare CrewList type as "observablecollection" instead of "List" It will update the view when you add each employee.

```
ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel> CrewList
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
 public List<EmployeeModel> CrewList
{
    get { return _crewList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref (_crewList), value); }
}
```

to

```
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel> CrewList {get;set}
```

This will automatically call the NotifyCollectionChange event on the collection.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196968/observablecollection-vs-list) post contains more information on the difference between list and observable collections.