# UWP - Binding Data Not Working - Empty ListView

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm currently trying to do one-way data binding inside of a listview, so that when my application launches, it will open a method, check for incoming packages, populate a list, and bind that list to a listview that will then show each package with its information. For some reason, however, the ListView isn't actually populating. I have debugged, and all of the back-end code is working fine -- the local variables, such as the package models and the list of models, are all populating perfectly. However, the ListView doesn't hold any content, and when I look at the local variable, it shows each content piece as completely empty.

Here is my code:

**DeliveryPlannerData.cs**

```
    public static List<ShipmentModel> shipments { get; set; } = new List<ShipmentModel>();

    public async static void populateDeliveryPlanner(string startDate, string endDate)
    {
        var deliveryPlanner = await DeliveryPlanner.DeliveryPlannerRequest(startDate, endDate);
        //if (panel.Children.Count > 0)
        //    panel.Children.Clear();

        try
        {
            List<string> trackingNumber = deliveryPlanner["trackingNumber"];
            List<string> lastScanDate = deliveryPlanner["lastScanDate"];
            List<string> scheduledDelivery = deliveryPlanner["scheduledDelivery"];
            List<string> status = deliveryPlanner["status"];


            for (int i = 0; i < trackingNumber.Count; i++)
            { 
                shipments.Add(new ShipmentModel(
                    trackingNumber[i], lastScanDate[i], scheduledDelivery[i], getStatus(status[i])
                ));
                var v = shipments;
            }

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            var error = e;
        }
    } // populateDeliveryPlanner
```

**ShipmentModel.cs**

```
    public class ShipmentModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string TrackingNumber;
    public string LastScanDate;
    public string ScheduledDelivery;
    public string Status;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public ShipmentModel(string trackingNumber, string lastScanDate, string scheduledDelivery, string status)
    {
        TrackingNumber = trackingNumber;
        LastScanDate = lastScanDate;
        ScheduledDelivery = scheduledDelivery;
        Status = status;
    }

    public string trackingNumber
    {
        get { return this.TrackingNumber; }
        set
        {
            this.TrackingNumber = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

**DeliveryPlanner.xaml**

`<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShipmentModelTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding shipments, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="19,12,19,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>`

This is obviously not all of the code in each document, but it's the important parts.
I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong? The listView refuses to populate.

Comment: try making `shipments` an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hey, thank you! That worked perfectly. If you don't mind, could you explain why changing from List<> to ObservableCollection<> made this work?

Comment: Yes you need ObservableCollection. See difference here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4197068/4585476

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed based on the comments above, you need to use `ObservableCollection<T>` in order to get this to work. The reason though is a little obscure.

When you set your View's `DataContext` property, the View goes out to the bound properties and binds them, once... So if on initialization of the `DataContext` there is nothing in your collection then you're not going to get anything in the view.

To fix this we implement this interface called `INotifyPropertyChanged`. We use this on ViewModels and Models.

What this interface does is it gives you an event handler that you can use to update the UI. You send your property name off in the event and when the UI handles it, it captures the property name, checks to see if it has anything bound to that property, and if it does, goes out and updates it with the new value.

Here's where `ObservableCollection` comes into play. Your `ObservableCollection` will update the `UI` for you so that you don't need to call your property changed event.

As you can see from the [MSDN Documentation on `ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), it Implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, 
    INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Had you called a property changed event after adding items to your list, you wouldn't need an `ObservableCollection` either.

Here is an [Article on How DataBinding works](http://www.dotnet-guide.com/data-binding-overview.html)

Here is the [MSDN Documentation on INotifyPropertyChanged](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=inotifypropertychanged)

Here is an [example on how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx)