# I can't use method Filter on ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, viewmodel

On my `viewModel` I developed this code that will allow me to implement a research filter:

```cs
        public ICollection<Nc> Ncs
        {
            get
            {
                var ncs = _ncManager.Ncs;

                _ncCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ncs);
                _ncCollectionView.Filter = _DoesNcMatchFileNameFilter;

                return ncs;
            }
        }
        private ICollectionView _ncCollectionView;
```

This method works, but if I try to implement another similar method in another `viewModel`:

```cs
    private ObservableCollection<Material> _materials;
    public ObservableCollection<Material> materials
    {
       get
       {
          var materials = Material.Name;
          _materialCollectionView = (CollectionViewSource)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(materials);
          _materialCollectionView.Filter = _DoesMaterialMatchFileNameFilter;
    
          return Materials;
       }
    }
    private CollectionViewSource _materialCollectionView;
```

I get an error: `CollectionViewSrouce.Filter can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=".`

Why can't I do the same thing? What did I do wrong?

I've tried to read this page [ObservableCollection<> vs. List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196968/observablecollection-vs-list) but it didn't help me.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @sommmen I edited the post, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should `_materialCollectionView` not be of type `ICollectionView`?

So:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Material> _materials;
    public ObservableCollection<Material> materials
    {
       get
       {
          var materials = Material.Name;
          _materialCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(materials);
          _materialCollectionView.Filter = _DoesMaterialMatchFileNameFilter;
    
          return Materials;
       }
    }
    private ICollectionView _materialCollectionView;
```