# SwipeView only responsive on some rows after executing a swipe! (until page manullay navigated)

Tags: listview, xamarin, refresh, swipeview

I have a complex listview comprised of a header template to group collections within a collection, I used the tutorial below which uses the example of grouping rooms by hotels within a listview:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview-with-a-sub-listview-mvvm-pattern/

I've added SwipeView to the items, but after one swipe to delete an item from a sub collection, the swipe gestures only respond on random rows.

This seems like a bug, possibly due to my use of my layered model/view model structure?

Any advice or tips on this? I've used both SwipeItems and SwipeItemView but neither made a difference. Also, it's sometimes the first items in the grid that don't swipe but the last items do...

I've also used InitialiseComponent after an item is removed from the collection but I don't like how the page scrolls to the top, and scrolltoasync does look great either.

My ListView's ItemSource is an ObservableCollection that contains sub Observable collections in it - LogItems, with FictionList, HistoryList, etc. When I get the retrieved item swipes, carrry out a foreach on the subcollections to remove it from the collection and the UI updates accordingly. However, then not all items are swipable....

I've been struggling with this bug so any help would be appreciated.

```
    <Grid x:Name="Grid2" Margin="0,-23,0,0" 
             MinimumHeightRequest="500" 
              BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              VerticalOptions="Fill" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackLayout x:Name="Stack" Padding="0,15,1,20" 
             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                         VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="1200" 
                         >
                    <ListView
                        x:Name="categoriesList"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                        HeightRequest="10"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="false"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding LogItems}"
                        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                        RefreshCommand="{Binding ExecuteRefreshItemsCommand}"
                            SeparatorVisibility="None"                      
                            >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate >
           

        <ViewCell Height="70" >
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 

    VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="White">                                        
                             <SwipeView>
                                  <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                       <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal" SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="Close">
                                            <SwipeItem
                                                 Text = "Delete" IconImageSource="deleteIcon3.png" BackgroundColor="Red" Invoked="SwipeView_SwipeInitiated"/>                      
                                       </SwipeItems>
       

                            </SwipeView.RightItems>
                               <SwipeView.Content>  
                                    <Grid> 

        <Label
        Grid.Row="1"                                                          
        Grid.Column="0"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        FontAttributes="None"                                       
        Text="{Binding .Log.Name }"
        TextColor="Black"
        Margin="0, 0,0, 0"
        Padding="10,10,0,0"
        FontFamily="Hiragino Sans"
        FontSize="14"
        HeightRequest="53"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        />

...

</Grid>


Code behind

        public void SwipeView_SwipeInitiated(object sender, 
        EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = sender as SwipeItemView;
            myLogsModel model = item.BindingContext as myLogsModel;

                if (model.BookCategory == "Fiction")
                {
                    foreach (var q in ViewModel.FictionList)
                    {
                        if (q.Name == model.Name)
                        {
                            ViewModel.BookList.Remove(q);                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

 //model - myLogsModel
        if (model.Log.LogCategory == "Fiction")
        {
            foreach (var q in ViewModel.FictionList)
            {
                if (q.MealName == model.Log.Name)
                {
                    ViewModel.FictionList.Remove(q);
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    ViewModel.DeleteLog(q);   
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I then, use a try-catch to clear the list and re-add with new sub collection data which works:

```
 try
        {
            if (ViewModel.IsBusy)
                return;
            ViewModel.IsBusy = true;
            ViewModel.LogItems.Clear();

            ObservableCollection<BookTypes> categoryitems = new ObservableCollection<BookTypes>() {
             new BookTypes("Fiction", ViewModel.FictionList),
             new BookTypes("History", ViewModel.HistoryList),
             new BookTypes("Politics", ViewModel.PoliticsList),
            };

            if (categoryitems != null && categoryitems.Count > 0)
            {   
                ViewModel.LogItems.Add(new LogTypesModel(types));
                ViewModel.OnPropertyChanged("LogItems");
            }
            else { ViewModel.IsEmpty = true; }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            ViewModel.IsBusy = false;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix it or find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **ObservableCollection** instead of **IList** .**ObservableCollection** also implements **INotifyCollectionChanged** interface while List doesn't. It will update UI when we add or remove items .

In your case , when you remove an item from `categoryitems` . The listview will not refresh . So the swipe event will never been invoked any more .

For more details you could check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196968/observablecollection-vs-list) ,

Comment: Hi Lucas, thank you for your support! I've changed all of my lists to o/collections but I'm still experiencing this odd behaviour. When I have 5 items in a list and delete the top one, the 2nd item works (can swipe) but the rest dont. When I have 4 items in the list and delete the bottom one, none of the 3 remaining work and when I have 3 items in the list and delete the 2nd one, the remaining top item works but the bottom one doesn't! Could you advise on this behaviour? All grid attributes are bound to the same values, the same structure so it shouldn't make a difference which row is swiped..

Comment: I can get the swipeview to work correctly if I initializecomponent afterwards but then this causes to the page to scroll up and scrolltoasync using scrolly isnt working onappearing as expected...Do you have any further advice on this?

Comment: UPDATE: I upgraded my Xamarin.Forms to 5.0.0.1931 so now all rows respond by displaying the swipeviewitem however, the swipe behaviour is nto responding correctly - no slide is shown, just the appearance of the revealled delete button on click....

Comment: Could you share a sample so that I can test it on my side