# Xamarin Form Picker - ItemDisplayBinding not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Xamarin Form Picker - ItemDisplayBinding not working**

I am trying to populate my Picker with a property of the objects in the ItemsSource, essentially exactly how it is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding

Here is what I have so far:

**Xaml**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:Model />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

---

```
<Picker Title="Select a Profession" ItemsSource="{Binding Professions}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" />
```

**Model - Binded**

```
public List<Profession> Professions { get; set; }
```

**Profession Object**

```
public class Profession
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So going by Microsoft's docs, the *Name* property should display, but it does not and in Visual Studio (For Mac - 2019), it doesn't event recognise *Name* as a property, just gives me the option of *Professions* again.

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by changing `List` to an `ObservableCollection`. I was trying to populate my picker in an async method and an `ObservableCollection` implements the `INotifyCollectionChangedInterface`

Reference:
[ObservableCollection<> vs. List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196968/observablecollection-vs-list)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this in your page.cs

For example

in MainPage.xaml.cs after InitializeComponent(); put the name of the ViewModel

```
        BindingContext = new MonkeysPageViewModel();
```

Like in the example online https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UserInterface/MonkeyAppPicker/MonkeyApp/Views/MonkeysPage.xaml.cs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippets,I think you haven't using the **[binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings)** properly.I have tested it your code on my side and it works like a charm.Below is the code snippets for your reference.

Code in Xaml:

```
 <Picker Title="Select a Profession" ItemsSource="{Binding Professions}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" />
```

Code in .cs:

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
        public ObservableCollection<Profession> Professions { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Profession>();
        public MainPage()
       {
            InitializeComponent();

            Professions.Add(new Profession { Name = "Teacher" });
            Professions.Add(new Profession { Name = "Doctor" });
            Professions.Add(new Profession { Name = "Astronaut" });

            BindingContext = this;  
        }
   }
  public class Profession
  {
        public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```